Image of center of the algebra group CG in CG-module
I was studying representation theory when a question came to my mind.
Consider a matrix irreducible representation of a group G. How is it possible to prove that the associated CG-module is such that every element of its center is associated to a scalar matrix?
I know that the center of the general linear group is made up of all and only the scalar matrices, but a group homomorphism does not (in general) preserve the center. How come it happens in this case?


This will not generally be true, you need to assume that the representation is irreducible. 2. Schur's lemma.


@LukasHeger I'll add it to the question. But how can it be proved in that case?

Multiplication by a central element of the group algebra defines an endomorphism of representations. Now apply Schur's lemma.

@LukasHeger What do you mean by "endomorphism of representations"?

I mean a homomorphism of representations from the given representation to itself. Some would call this an intertwiner or maybe there are other names, too.

@LukasHeger So it's a homomorphism of a homomorphism?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
